# How to non-interactively configure the Linux kernel build?

Tags: linux, configuration, kernel

Is there any method to configure linux kernel in such way (just an example):

```
make config CONFIG_OPTION=y && make config CONFIG_OPTION1=no CONFIG_OPTION3=64 CONFIG_OPTION4=/path/
```

and all the dependencies and alternatives of these configuration options will be set automatically in non-interactive mode.

Comment: Here is a script that automates Linux kernel configuration with dependency resolution: [Kernel Expect (kernelexpect)](https://github.com/perkint/kernelexpect)

Comment: The kernel has a tool (./scripts/config) to change specific options on .config, for example: `./scripts/config --set-val CONFIG_OPTION y`

Answer (score 3):

**Option I:**

The [qconfig](http://math.berkeley.edu/~vojta/qconfig.html) tool seems to serve the purpose, albeit depends on what interface you'd prefer. It takes an input file with the `CONFIG_ directives` that you'd want changed, and changes them. I didn't try it yet.

I didn't try it yet, but it doesn't look like it has an interface via command line arguments, along the lines of what you described.

**Option II:**

`sed -i 's:CONFIG_X=y:# CONFIG_X is not set:g' .config`

It's strange that non-interactive configuration seems to not get attention at all. It's certainly not applicable in general, but when you need to just flip a few switches (with few or no dependencies), e.g., a make target, then it would be very useful, more user-friendly than directly using `sed`, and better than maintaining `.config-with-X`, `.config-without-X`.

Comment: `scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh` is a built-in script that also uses `sed`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309264/32558

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to hand build the `.config` file with the required options. This would of course require **all** of the configuration options to be given, so it would be applicable in case of minor changes to an existing interactively-created `.config` file.

If you are asking about using the current `.config` but only changing some flags via the `make`, than I don't know. But you might try to edit the `.config` file via a script and then run `make`.

Comment: I tried to use sed for this purpose (changing only some flags in current .config), but in the case of many different .config files it is very difficult to take into account all dependencies and alternatives.

Comment: Indeed. The kernel compilation system is quite complex. If you could explain more about what you are trying to accomplish, we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Answer moved to: [How to script make menuconfig to automate Linux kernel build configuration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224887/how-to-script-make-menuconfig-to-automate-linux-kernel-build-configuration/450407#450407)

**Config fragments**

**[`scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.7/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh)**

Usage:

```
git checkout v4.9

make x86_64_defconfig

grep -E 'CONFIG_(DEBUG_INFO|GDB_SCRIPTS)[= ]' .config
# # CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is not set

# GDB_SCRIPTS depends on CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO in lib/Kconfig.debug

cat <<EOF >.config-fragment
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
EOF

# Order is important here. Must be first base config, then fragment.
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment

grep -E 'CONFIG_(DEBUG_INFO|GDB_SCRIPTS)[= ]' .config
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
# CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
```

Process substitution does *not* work unfortunately:

```
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig \
    <( printf 'CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y\nCONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y\n' )
```

because of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164109/32558

`merge_config.sh` is a simple front-end for the `make alldefconfig` target.

When cross compiling, `ARCH` must be exported when you run `merge_config.sh`, e.g.:

```
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
make defconfig
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
```

Buildroot automates it with `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414968/how-do-i-configure-the-linux-kernel-within-buildroot

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505164/how-do-you-non-interactively-turn-on-features-in-a-linux-kernel-config-file