# Why does BASH process substitution not work with some commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, process-substitution

On occasion process substitution will not work as expected. Here is an example:

Input:

```
gcc <(echo 'int main(){return 0;}')
```

Output:

```
/dev/fd/63: file not recognized: Illegal seek
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Input:

But it works as expected when used with a different command:

```
grep main <(echo 'int main(){return 0;}')
```

Output:

```
int main(){return 0;}
```

I have noticed similar failures with other commands (i.e. the command expecting the file from the process substitution can't use `/dev/fd/63` or similar). This failure with `gcc` is just the most recent.  Is there some general rule that I should be aware of to determine when process substitution will fail in this way and should not be used?

I am using this BASH version on Ubuntu 12.04 (I've also seen this in arch and debian):
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: `illegal seek` looks like the answer - the `|pipe` that `bash` points the executed program to is not a seekable file. probably if you cannot successfully `echo data | command /dev/fd/0` at a program then you'll have similar luck w/ `<(cmd)`. It doesn't provide an on-disk file - it just substitutes an argument that points to a pipe file descriptor.

Comment: In this particular case, although gcc *can* accept standard input, it (by default) uses the filename extension to determine the language. So try `gcc -xc <(echo 'int main(){return 0;}')` (which sets the language to `C` explicitly).

Comment: I was directed here in response to my own question, which seems likely to be another example of this. https://superuser.com/questions/1243405. Thanks for phrasing the question better than I was able.

Comment: In [fish shell](https://fishshell.com), you could use `psub` command, and do `gcc (echo 'int main(){return 0;}' | psub -s .c)`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Process substitution results in a special file (like `/dev/fd/63` in your example) that behaves like the read end of a named pipe. This file can be opened and read, but not written, not seeked.

Commands that treat their arguments as pure streams work while commands that expect to seek in files they are given (or write to them) won't work. The kind of command that will work is what is usually considered a filter: `cat`, `grep`, `sed`, `gzip`, `awk`, etc... An example of a command that won't work is an editor like `vi` or a file operation like `mv`.

`gcc` wants to be able to perform random access on its input files to detect what language they are written in. If you instead give `gcc` a hint about the input file's language, it's happy to stream the file:

```
gcc -x c <(echo 'int main(){return 0;}')
```

The simpler more straightforward form without process substitution also works:

```
echo 'int main(){return 0;}' | gcc -x c -
```

Note that this is not specific to `bash`. All shells that support process substitution behave the same way.

Comment: +1 for the gcc workaround but I'm not sure about your point concerning files. The `<()` format should act like a file for all intents and purposes. In fact, I don't know of any commands that expect a file that won't be happy with `<()`. The ones that don't work are those that expect file _names_, not files. For example, `grep -f` expects a file and works fine with `<()`.

Comment: @terndon For sure `<()` produces a file *name* (the construct expands to `/proc/self/fd/something` on my system). This name, when opened, acts like the read end of a named pipe (`S_IFIFO`) rather than a regular file (`S_IFREG`) in that is supports `read()` and others but not `seek()`.

Comment: Note that `zsh` supports a 3rd form of process substitution that uses temporary files especially for that purpose: `gcc =(echo 'int main(){return 0;}')`

Comment: [maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30832327/1423333), but works with `<(echo '...')` but not with `<(git show ...)`. any idea why that could be?

Comment: @JörnHees, I did a few quick tests and both `git show ... | gcc -x c ... -` and `gcc -x c <(git show ...)` work for me.

Comment: GCC does not "perform random access on its input files to detect what language they are written in." It just looks at the filename's extension. If the filename does not have an extension (or if it has one which isn't recognized), GCC assumes the file is an object file or linker script and passes it to `ld` (which does detect object formats). `-x` is not a hint; it is a declaration. If you specify `-x f95`, GCC will pass the file to the Fortran-95 compiler regardless of its name or contents. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html

Comment: I have a current issue with process substitution while using the GNU/awk readfile extension, which appears to discard non-seekable files completely. I suspect there is an interaction with mmap.