# Using process substitution to trick programs expecting files, with specific extensions as argument?

Tags: bash, filenames, process-substitution

Here is my use case: the command line utility `melt` can accept a file name, with the extension `.melt` on the command line, and open it; as an example, this is a proper `test_p.melt` file:

```
colour:blue
out=24

colour:red
out=48
```

... which opens and plays with `melt test_p.melt`.

Now, the thing is that `.melt` files do not support comments, which I wish they did (you'll get error messages for any line that contains an unparsable argument, including those with, say, a `#`). So here is a commented `test_c.melt` file:

```
# master comment here

colour:blue  # this is blue!
out=24

colour:red
out=48
```

Opening this in `melt` directly gives:

```
$ melt test_c.melt
Failed to load "# master comment here"
...
```

... and there is no blue screen shown.

So I thought - well, I can put in comments *anyway*, and then use Bash process substitution to filter the file with `sed`, and simply provide that to the `melt` application. First, tried a test with `cat`, which is successful:

```
$ cat <(sed 's/#.*$//' test_c.melt)



colour:blue  
out=24

colour:red
out=48
```

... looks good; *but*, if I try that with `melt`, it sees through my trickery:

```
$ melt <(sed 's/#.*$//' test_c.melt)
Failed to load "/dev/fd/62"
Failed to load "/dev/fd/62"
```

Basically, melt got the filename of the pipe Bash provided for the process substitution - but unfortunately, what `melt` does is that it processes `argv[i]` directly; and in case of a file, it needs to see a `.melt` extension in the filename; if it doesn't - the process fails.

So my question is: how could I use process substitution - so the filename of the pipe has a specific extension, in this case `.melt`? Basically, as a result of the substitution, I'd want a pipe filename of `/dev/fd/62.melt`, which I think will pass.

NB: of course, I can always do:

```
sed 's/#.*$//' test_c.melt > test_c_temp.melt
melt test_c_temp.melt
```

... but first, there are two commands here - and I'd want a one-liner pipeline; and for another, it opens up another problem of me thinking about removing temporary files afterwards, which I don't like.

Is this possible with Bash process substitution - or somehow with standard Linux tools?

Comment: Try `melt < <(sed 's/#.*$//' test_c.melt)`

Comment: Thanks @Costas - tried that, but apparently `melt` doesn't care about commands piped through `stdin`, since I get: `Usage: melt [options] [producer [name=value]* ]+` and a dump of program options. Cheers!

Comment: I have to read `man melt` on behalf of you. "*If no files are specified, the compression is applied to the **standard input***". So `sed 's/#.*$//' test_c.melt | melt > result.file` can work.

Comment: Thanks again, @Costas - unfortunately, that doesn't work either, at least not on my version of `melt` (MLT melt 0.6.2; "standard input" is not mentioned in this version's `man melt`), since for that command, again I get `Usage: melt [options] [producer [name=value]* ]+` and a dump. Cheers!

Comment: I think you have to read `man melt` on your machine. If you cannot find answer post in on http://pastebin.com and post link here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility would be to point `melt` to a filesystem that shows modified copies of files. [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) is a generic way to build filesystem driver implemented by an ordinary program and requiring no privileges. There are [many FUSE filesystems around](http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/wiki/FileSystems/), and there's a good chance that one of them can help you. The idea is to provide a mount point where reading a `.melt` file reads the “real” file but with comments filtered out.

[ScriptFS](https://code.google.com/p/scriptfs/) looks promising (but I've never used it). Something like this should work:

```
mkdir ~/uncommented-melt
scriptfs -p "$HOME/bin/uncomment-melt;&*.melt" ~/work ~/uncommented-melt
```

where `~/work` is the root of the tree that contains your `.melt` files and `~/bin/uncomment-melt` is

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/#.*$//' "$1"
```

Then if you have a file `~/work/test_c.melt` with comments, you can run `melt ~/uncommented-melt/test_c.melt`.

Other potential helpful FUSE filesystems:

- [Execfuse](https://github.com/vi/execfuse) — lets you build a simple FUSE driver with shell scripts
- [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) or other FUSE filesystems that transparently uncompress files: define the stripping of comments as an uncompression rule.

Comment: Many thanks for that @Gilles - I accepted this answer, because it answer the question generically. Unfortunately, I couldn't quite get `scriptfs` to work - here is a command log I saved at the time (AFAICR, stackexchange crashed that day `:)`) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e9ee5e8c53d1b4c3c736 - so I ended up using a `bash` script approach which I posted below. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

With the `zsh` shell, you can use the `=(...)` form of process substitution (which uses temporary files instead of `/dev/fd/x` files and pipes) for which you can specify a suffix:

```
(TMPSUFFIX=.melt; melt =(sed 's/#.*$//' test_c.melt))
```

See `info zsh TMPSUFFIX` (assuming the `info` pages are installed, you may need to install a `zsh-doc` package) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it turns out that in my specific case, these kind of melt scripts are to be interpreted strictly as commands line arguments; so just the one `sed` in the OP doesn't quite cut it (plus, there are other things like profiles that can be set). So here is what I ended up doing - can probably serve as inspiration in other cases which the title of the OP would cover.

I eventually settled on using this: make a `test.shmelt` file, which is actually a `bash` script that contains my commented `melt` script code; make this file executable `chmod +x test.shmelt`; then after editing the script, run it as `./test.shmelt`.

Upon running, it will create a "cleaned up" `test.melt` file in `/tmp`, and call `melt` on this file instead. Since `melt` usually keeps running in terminal after the end of its programme, with a trap on SIGINT this temporary file can be cleaned up when Ctrl-C is pressed (but doesn't have to).

In that way, I still have comments; can edit quickly in the source file and run melt and see results; and have a file "cleaned up" of comments too, that I can use later.

Here is the code of `test.shmelt`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# call with: ./test.shmelt


#TMLTFILE="test.melt" # for final export
TMLTFILE="${0%%.shmelt}.melt" # for final export

function finished() { echo ; } ; # use this when testing or montaging to keep exported (tmp) .melt file; uncomment the below to remove the tmp file
#~ function finished() { rm /tmp/"$TMLTFILE"; echo "fin1 $0" ; } ; trap finished SIGINT ;

echo 'Remember `pulseaudio --start` to hear audio with `melt`!'
pulseaudio --check
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    pulseaudio --start
fi

DIRNAME=$(readlink -f $(dirname $0))
PROFILE="square_ntsc"


echo "
# the profile doesn't work from here;
# still has to be specified on command line
# but including it here so the path is saved for testing
#~ -profile
#~ ${PROFILE}

-video-track

  # can avoid pixmap: here, but that s the producer;
  # qimage: also works
  # NB it is NOT '-out 1645'; but 'out=1645'!!
  /media/myimg/%05d.bmp
  in=0
  out=1645
  #~ length=1645
  #~ loop=0
  #~ eof=stop

-audio-track

  /media/mysnd/snd.wav
  in=0
  out=1645
  #~ loop=0
  #~ eof=stop

#-consumer xml # doesn't work here

" | sed -e 's/#.*$//' -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' > ${TMLTFILE}

# the sed: remove comments; remove indents; remove empty lines; remove spaces at end of line


# eof: one of: stop, loop, continue or pause (eof=stop)
# to loop, use `melt eof=loop ...` (but make sure first,
#  that the edit as a whole stops - use xml to check!)
# due to caching issues, preview pieces (up to ~300 frames) like this:
melt eof=loop -profile ${PROFILE} ${TMLTFILE} in=200 out=400

# must have profile here, for checking w/ -consumer xml (else segfault)
# this command may add additional producers to the xml!:
## melt -profile ${PROFILE} ${TMLTFILE} -consumer xml

# use this to generate xml if needed:
#melt -profile ${PROFILE} $(cat ${TMLTFILE} | tr '\n' ' ') -consumer xml

# if exited normally, cleanup:
finished
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I'll try to answer the title question in a way that would've been useful to me.

This is related: [Why does BASH process substitution not work with some commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164107/why-does-bash-process-substitution-not-work-with-some-commands)

So the specific problem I was trying to solve was this:

1. I have an image converter;
2. it converts from [insert random format] to simple formats like BMP/PNM/TGA;
3. I want to convert to JPEG, so need to chain it with ImageMagick `convert`;
4. I don't want to use temporary files.

So, unfortunately, the tool doesn't like to output to stdout/fds/pipes because it derives the output format from the output filename's extension. So how to trick it?

Create a symbolic link with the appropriate extension to `/dev/fd/N` and use that as the "temporary file".

Example:

```
ln -s /dev/fd/4 temp.pnm
[TOOL] -i [INPUTFILE] -o temp.pnm 4>&1 | convert - [OUTPUT.JPG]
```