# Can't run file(1) on output of file descriptor, pipe, fifo, device, etc

Tags: files, rhel, process-substitution

I want to run the `file(1)` command on the output of another command, but all I get is

```
$ file -sL <(echo \#include \<stdio.h\>)
/dev/fd/63: ERROR: (null)
```

This works as expected in file-5.04 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8), but not in file-5.14 (Wind River Linux 6.0.0.17).

Comment: Does it work if you use standard input `file -s - < <(echo \#include \<stdio.h\>)` (and is that an acceptable solution for your use case)?

Comment: Well I'll be darned ... you know that occurred to me as I started my task, but it wasn't documented in the man page so I didn't try it, should have gone back and tried it when file descriptors didn't work! Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice to know why the process substitution doesn't work though - let's hope someone knowledgeable chimes in

Comment: ... perhaps because it's not seekable? [Why does BASH process substitution not work with some commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164107/why-does-bash-process-substitution-not-work-with-some-commands)

Comment: Hmm, then why would it work on another version?

Comment: @eewanco the bug wasn't present in older versions. In this case, file(1) doesn't try to seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the libmagic library that `file` is using.

A simple workaround is a "useless use of cat":

```
echo '#! /bin/sh' | file -
cat /path/to/fifo-or-special | file -
```

---

The bug was first introduced in https://github.com/file/file/commit/fb6084e0f08:

```
commit fb6084e0f08aef8991afcb3eb74168a456601908
Author: Christos Zoulas <christos@zoulas.com>
Date:   Tue May 28 21:24:31 2013 +0000

    don't print a space if there was an error. (from Jan Kaluza)
```

It was then fixed, but *only* for block and character devices, NOT for FIFOs in https://github.com/file/file/commit/a9124dcb4e. An *incomplete* fix for `<(...)` on Linux was in https://github.com/file/file/commit/adbe541c32.

The fix for devices could be replicated for FIFOs. See the patch at the end of the answer (apply by hand because this site mangles tabs and keep in mind that it's against a MIRROR ONLY repo).

But that still leaves:

```
mkfifo fifo; file -s fifo

fifo: writable, no read permission
```

Stupid and wrong, because the FIFO has read permission.

Repairing this will mean either rewriting half of libmagic, or add yet another couple of ifdef spaghetti and special cases to the horrible mess.

```
diff --git a/src/fsmagic.c b/src/fsmagic.c
index 5204f20d..20b7f438 100644
--- a/src/fsmagic.c
+++ b/src/fsmagic.c
@@ -270,8 +270,10 @@ file_fsmagic(struct magic_set *ms, const char *fn, struct stat *sb)
    /* TODO add code to handle V7 MUX and Blit MUX files */
 #ifdef S_IFIFO
    case S_IFIFO:
-       if((ms->flags & MAGIC_DEVICES) != 0)
+       if((ms->flags & MAGIC_DEVICES) != 0) {
+           return 0;
            break;
+       }
        if (mime) {
            if (handle_mime(ms, mime, "fifo") == -1)
                return -1;
```

Comment: Did your compiler not tell you that you could delete the `break`?  (-:

Comment: Not to excuse me for just monkeying the previous change, but it did not (gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0).