# How to script make menuconfig to automate Linux kernel build configuration?

Tags: bash, linux-kernel, make

I want to automate a Linux build but eventually get to a point where I need to run what seems to be a very manual step: `make menuconfig`.  This seems to synchronize configs between the OS and kernel configs?

```
cp git-tracked-config .config
make defconfig 
make menuconfig # <- how to automate/script this?
make V=s
```

Basically, how can I remove the call to `make menuconfig` for a build script?

As an aside, this is in reaction to a build error that seems to happen when I run without ever calling make menuconfig:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
```

Which seems to be there is a missing rule in a makefile perhaps because the makefile itself does NOT exist or the makefile has not been generated/morphed to contain that rule but that is a separate question.

There could be a smarter way to approach this alltogether.  Are there other configs that I'm not tracking but should (e.g. oldconfig)?

Comment: Have you tested `make olddefconfig`?

Comment: no, reading more about that now...  it's just so painful because any small experiment takes so long.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Linux kernel build-system provide many build targets, the best way to know about it is probably to do a `make help`:

```
Configuration targets:
  config      - Update current config utilising a line-oriented program
  nconfig         - Update current config utilising a ncurses menu based program
  menuconfig      - Update current config utilising a menu based program
  xconfig     - Update current config utilising a QT based front-end
  gconfig     - Update current config utilising a GTK based front-end
  oldconfig   - Update current config utilising a provided .config as base
  localmodconfig  - Update current config disabling modules not loaded
  localyesconfig  - Update current config converting local mods to core
  silentoldconfig - Same as oldconfig, but quietly, additionally update deps
  defconfig   - New config with default from ARCH supplied defconfig
  savedefconfig   - Save current config as ./defconfig (minimal config)
  allnoconfig     - New config where all options are answered with no
  allyesconfig    - New config where all options are accepted with yes
  allmodconfig    - New config selecting modules when possible
  alldefconfig    - New config with all symbols set to default
  randconfig      - New config with random answer to all options
  listnewconfig   - List new options
  olddefconfig    - Same as silentoldconfig but sets new symbols to their default value
  kvmconfig   - Enable additional options for guest kernel support
  tinyconfig      - Configure the tiniest possible kernel
```

As jimmij says in the comments, the interesting parts are in the `oldconfig` related targets.

Personally, I would recommend you to go for `silentoldconfig` (if nothing changed in the `.config` file or `olddefconfig` if you updated your `.config` file with a new kernel.

Comment: `randconfig` surprised me. Presumably used to test builds by generating unlikely combinations?

Comment: Yes, this is precisely used as a fuzzer for configuration file. See this question: [When compiling the Linux Kernel, what is the purpose of `make randconfig`?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270980/when-compiling-the-linux-kernel-what-is-the-purpose-of-make-randconfig) (on 'Ask Ubuntu' website).

Answer (score 3):

**[`merge_config.sh`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.7/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh) config fragments**

```
$ cd linux
$ git checkout v4.9
$ make x86_64_defconfig
$ grep -E 'CONFIG_(DEBUG_INFO|GDB_SCRIPTS)[= ]' .config
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is not set
$ # GDB_SCRIPTS depends on CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO in lib/Kconfig.debug.
$ cat <<EOF >.config-fragment
> CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
> CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
> EOF
$ # Order is important here. Must be first base config, then fragment.
$ ./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
$ grep -E 'CONFIG_(DEBUG_INFO|GDB_SCRIPTS)[= ]' .config
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
```

Process substitution does *not* work unfortunately:

```
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig \
    <( printf 'CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y\nCONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y\n' )
```

because of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164109/32558

`merge_config.sh` is a simple front-end for the `make alldefconfig` target.

When cross compiling, `ARCH` must be exported when you run `merge_config.sh`, e.g.:

```
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
make defconfig
./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
```

The merged output file can be specified explicitly with the `KCONFIG_CONFIG` environment variable; otherwise it just overwrites `.config`:

```
KCONFIG_CONFIG=some/path/.config ./scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh .config .config-fragment
```

Buildroot automates it with `BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENT_FILES`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414968/how-do-i-configure-the-linux-kernel-within-buildroot

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505164/how-do-you-non-interactively-turn-on-features-in-a-linux-kernel-config-file

Comment: thanks for help in comments on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943857/linux-kernel-live-debugging-how-its-done-and-what-tools-are-used/44226360#44226360  also can u please let me know which flag in `makefile` I have to add like `config_XYZ=y` to disable `linux kernel tcp stack` since I like to give a try to `Userspace TCP stack` that I downloaded

Comment: @user786 not sure about this. grep the Kconfig files to see if any interesting options show up. You can also try to search inside `make menuconfig` with `/`.

Comment: I plan to write in makefile the debug flags=y. Please confirm is this also correct way that I plan

Comment: @user786 which makefile? Linux kernel or your own? By debug flags do you mean a standard kernel config, or something else? For standard kernel configs, no need to patch makefiles. For non standard, then you might need to hack kernel source I suppose.

Comment: There is file with name `Makefile` which inside in the kernel downloaded source folder. For example when I downloaded linux-5.12.6 its inside that folder

Comment: File downloaded with linux source code from kernel.org that I plan to compile and install with make command..

Comment: @user786 OK, and what do you mean by "I plan to write in makefile the debug flags=y" more precisely? `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y` or something else?

Comment: I mean `where should I type CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`

Comment: @user786 see the code given in this answer.

Comment: I have successfully compiled the kernel with debug flags from your above link answer. thank u very much for this. now I want to debug Ethernet driver from `realTek` thats my nic card driver. Now I want to debug realTek `r8169` Ethernet driver  same way as the link answer which u gave. I know there is function `rtl_rx` in r8169_main.c file which called from NAPI `poll` handler. and inside that `rtl_rx` function `napi_gro_receive(&tp->napi, skb);` called and `napi_gro_receive` I beleive forward the packet up the kernel stack.

Comment: So are there any chances I can run and debug compiled kernel using qemu and check the `kernel tcp stack` 's functions call-stack -- `since there will be only kernel running in Qemu but can I see the packet going way up the kernel stack` following the driver 's  rtl_rx `napi_gro_receive` function call

Comment: @user786 great! Is there any specific reason why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943857/linux-kernel-live-debugging-how-its-done-and-what-tools-are-used/42316607#42316607 won't work?

Comment: I just like to ask since it wont be ubanu os. There is no userspace, just compiled kernel with debug flags so how to test the kernel tcp stack. How do I find the ip so I can send packets from some other system to check target compiled running kernel in qemu. Can I specify in qemu t)which ethernet device to use as hardware ?so Realtek Ethernet driver can be debugged. Other wise r8169 pci network driver will not be used and not running.

Comment: @user786 in general you just the only/easiest solution is to just setup userspace as well and run your content. My preferred way is with a Buildroot userland as shown at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue since I wanted to upgrade my CentOS kernel and needed to do it on several machines. Assume here my new CentOS kernel tree is in /linux-5.1 (I'm logged into the root account)

1. `cd /linux-5.1`
2. run `make menuconfig` and make your changes and save them to `.config`
3. copy the `/linux-5.1/.config` file to your development server
4. Now for your next machine to upgrade you'll copy `.config` file from
   your development server to `/linux-5.1/.config` on the new machine.

Hope this helps someone in the same predicament.