# What is the difference between 'make' and 'make oldconfig'

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, make

With regard to this question: [How to script make menuconfig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224887/how-to-script-make-menuconfig?newreg=d0d0531f52e74218a141005f29ba59b5), what is the difference between running `make` and `make oldconfig`?

I assume that if you run `make`, it uses the old `.config` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make oldconfig` is used to apply your old .config file to the newer
kernel.

For exapmle, you have `.config` file of your current kernel and you
downloaded new kernel and want to build your new kernel. Since very likely new kernel will have some new configuration options, you will need to update your config. The easiest way to do this is to run `make oldconfig`, which will prompt you questions about the new configuration options. (that is the ones your current `.config` file doesn't have)

Comment: `silentoldconfig` does that too, and better since dependencies are taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 4):

In the Linux kernel, `make` defaults to `silentoldconfig`, which does the same as `oldconfig`, and additionally automatically updates dependent configuration entries (configuration entries which depend on other values, *i.e.* `depends on` entries in `Kconfig` files).

Of course `make` then builds the kernel, whereas `make oldconfig` only updates the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for that, I hadn't noticed that `make oldconfig` only configures and does not do the build as well