# How to non-interactively configure the Linux kernel build? (Marked incorrectly as duplicated)

Tags: linux, kernel, configuration

Is there any method to configure linux kernel in such way (just an example):

```
make config CONFIG_OPTION=y && make config CONFIG_OPTION1=no CONFIG_OPTION3=64 CONFIG_OPTION4=/path/
```

and all the dependencies and alternatives of these configuration options will be set automatically in non-interactive mode.

---

Note: This question was asked previously ([How to non-interactively configure the Linux kernel build?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19905/)) but was marked as duplicated (although it is not, it asked a different thing). As I can't answer the original question, I am answering here.

Comment: That question points to a duplicate that still accepts answers and I agree with the duplicate.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel has a tool (`./scripts/config`) to change specific options on `.config`. Here is an example:

```
./scripts/config --set-val CONFIG_OPTION y
./scripts/config --set-val CONFIG_OPTION1 n
./scripts/config --set-str CONFIG_OPTION3 64
./scripts/config --set-str CONFIG_OPTION4 /path/
```